# Ovverride List View

Tags: list-view

I have a requirement to show more than 15 columns to be displayed in List Views and New Vf Page should be a replica of Standard :List Views page.I came to know that we have to Customize with Vf page.No idea how to start.Need Help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't technically override the standard list view, but you can still accomplish what you are asking:

1. Create your Visualforce page you'd like to override the list view with help StandardSetController as explained here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_list_views.htm
2. Create a Visualforce Tab and name it the same thing as the object.